# Convert logic to use Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8

I am learning how to use Streams in Java 8, and would like to understand how to convert the following example to a stream-based way.  I have made a couple attempts but can't get the stream-based way to compile. I think I'm getting tripped up with nested loops and variable references that seem to be lost.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Objects;

import gov.geo.argcci.product.parts.layers.PlatformMarkerLayer;

public class Test {

    public void java7Method(final Collection<Item> items) {
        for (final LayerHolder layerHolder : getLayerHolders()) {
            if (layerHolder.getLayer() instanceof MyLayer) {
                final MyLayer myLayer = (MyLayer) layerHolder.getLayer();
                final Item current = myLayer.getItem();
                if (current != null) {
                    for (final Item item : items) {
                        if (Objects.equals(item.getSomeKey(), current.getSomeKey())
                                && Objects.equals(item.getSomeOtherKey(), current.getSomeOtherKey())) {
                            final SomeObject someObject = getObjectBasedOnItem(current);
                            someObject.doSomething(layerHolder);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void java8Method(final Collection<Item> items) {
        getLayerHolders()
        .stream()
        .filter(layerHolder -> layerHolder.getLayer() instanceof MyLayer)
                .map(layerHolder -> (MyLayer) layerHolder.getLayer())
                .map(layerHolder -> layerHolder.getItem())
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .forEach(current->{
                    items.stream()
                    .filter(Objects.equals(item.getSomeKey(), current.getSomeKey()) && Objects.equals(item.getSomeOtherKey(), current.getSomeOtherKey()));              
//                      final SomeObject someObject = getObjectBasedOnItem(current);
//                      someObject.doSomething(layerHolder);
                });
    }

    // The Code below this line is auto-generated to make sure example can compile without errors
    private SomeObject getObjectBasedOnItem(Item current) {
        return null;
    }
    private Collection<LayerHolder> getLayerHolders() {
        return null;
    }
    private class Item {
        public Object getSomeKey() {
            return null;
        }
        public Object getSomeOtherKey() {
            return null;
        }
    }
    private class LayerHolder {
        public MyLayer getLayer() {
            return null;
        }
    }
    private class MyLayer {
        public Item getItem() {
            return null;
        }
    }
    private class SomeObject {
        public void doSomething(LayerHolder layerHolder) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors that you got?

Comment: in your second filter you just need to prepend `item -> ` to make it a lambda

Comment: Maybe the answer to this super-complicated code is **not** to make it even more complicated by pulling it into streams. But maybe by reading about the "single layer of abstraction" principle and slicing this un-maintainable piece of code into something that is remotely understandable to human readers. And you know, what value do all those "final" keywords add to that already polluted code?

Comment: and then a simple map should do.

Comment: but you may want to rethink the logic first. You are looping on items, but are acting on a layer in the loop. apparently you are just validating if there is a matching item, so possibly there is a simple filter that can be done.

Comment: So the method takes a list of items, and looks for similar items (based on a compound key) which are stored deep in objects. I then have to lookup a SomeObject based on the item and do something with the outer layer object.  I'm not sure offhand how this could be simplified because of the need to reference the outer layer and the innermost item

Comment: As njzk2 already said, your Java 8 variant lacks an `item -> ` before the `filter` function. However, even the Java 7 variant contains a logical error: you are iterating over `items` but not actually using that item, but working on `current`, which will be the same for every matching `item`. If, on the other hand, you only want to check whether there is a match (i.e. not expecting more than one match), you should also code it as such.

Comment: That's because item and current are not exact matches. I need to work on the current that 'matches' the item

Comment: Still, if there are more than one matching `item`, you will perform the same work multiple times on exactly the same `current`.

Comment: I gotcha. In this particular case there is only one, but I should have added a break statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A direct translation of your Java 7 code would be

```
public void java8Method(final Collection<Item> items) {
    getLayerHolders().forEach(layerHolder -> {
        Optional.of(layerHolder)
                .map(LayerHolder::getLayer)
                .filter(MyLayer.class::isInstance)
                .map(l -> ((MyLayer)l).getItem())
                .ifPresent(current-> items.stream()
                    .filter(item ->
                        Objects.equals(item.getSomeKey(), current.getSomeKey())
                     && Objects.equals(item.getSomeOtherKey(), current.getSomeOtherKey()))
                    .forEach(ignored ->
                             getObjectBasedOnItem(current).doSomething(layerHolder))
            );
    });
}
```

except that this doesn’t call `getLayer()` twice.

But I have the strong feeling that what you actually want to do is

```
public void java8Method(final Collection<Item> items) {
    getLayerHolders().forEach(layerHolder ->
        Optional.of(layerHolder)
                .map(LayerHolder::getLayer)
                .filter(MyLayer.class::isInstance)
                .map(l -> ((MyLayer)l).getItem())
                .filter(current-> items.stream()
                    .anyMatch(item ->
                        Objects.equals(item.getSomeKey(), current.getSomeKey())
                     && Objects.equals(item.getSomeOtherKey(), current.getSomeOtherKey())))
                .ifPresent(current ->
                           getObjectBasedOnItem(current).doSomething(layerHolder))
    );
}
```

Generally, you should think more about the actual program logic than converting pre-Java 8 code to Stream API using code…

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the outer layer object in the `doSomething` method. So you can't map to the Item object in the stream.

Probably the best decision is to try to simplify the design. Using streams is not going to make it more simple to implement.

In your version without streams, the inner for loop is testing if the item of the layer is inside the list, this could be another filter in the stream.

The code could be:

```
public void java8Method(final Collection<Item> items) {
    getLayerHolders()
    .stream()
    .filter(layerHolder -> layerHolder.getLayer() instanceof MyLayer)
    .filter(layerHolder -> Objects.nonNull(((MyLayer) layerHolder.getLayer()).getItem()))
    .filter(layerHolder->{ Item current = ((MyLayer) layerHolder.getLayer()).getItem();
                           return items.stream()
                                   .anyMatch(item->Objects.equals(item.getSomeKey(), current.getSomeKey()) && 
                                                   Objects.equals(item.getSomeOtherKey(), current.getSomeOtherKey())); })
    .forEach(layerHolder-> getObjectBasedOnItem(((MyLayer) layerHolder.getLayer()).getItem()).doSomething(layerHolder));
}
```

Comment: Code duplication is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to make it a single streaming function makes it very difficult to read and maintain.

Implementing it in stages and breaking out Predicates would be ideal.

This implementation gets you both readable, maintainable code and streaming functionality.

```
public void java8Method(Collection<Item> items)
  {
    Predicate<LayerHolder> hasMyLayer = lh -> MyLayer.class
        .isInstance(lh.getLayer());

    Predicate<MyLayer> hasNonNullItem = ml -> Objects.nonNull(ml.getItem());

    Predicate<MyLayer> hasMatchingItem = (ml) -> items.stream()
        .filter(i -> i.getSomeKey().equals(ml.getItem().getSomeKey()))
        .filter(i -> i.getSomeOtherKey().equals(ml.getItem().getSomeOtherKey()))
        .count() > 0;

    getLayerHolders().stream().filter(lh -> hasMyLayer.test(lh))
        .filter(lh -> hasNonNullItem.test(lh.getLayer()))
        .filter(lh -> hasMatchingItem.test(lh.getLayer()))
        .forEach(lh -> getObjectBasedOnItem(lh.getLayer().getItem())
            .doSomething(lh));
  }
```